# Why do drupal views css class names get changed

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Currently experiencing an irritating quirk of Drupal views where it will change the provided css class name.

For example, if I add the class `container_12` it will be rendered as `container-12`.

Any idea how to turn this off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views doest it because of [CSS codeing standards](http://drupal.org/node/302199) from Drupal. You can change the behavior  with `phptemplate_preprocess_views_view(&$vars)`. Here is an example.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class');
  if (!empty($css_class)) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $vars['css_class'];
  }
}
```

Also, I just can advise you to change you css, if you use a framework you can easily find a base theme with you framework on drupal.org.

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but I ended up just hacking it with a str_replace in an overridden .tpl.php file as I wanted to get going with project.